# Prove using calculus or otherwise the following inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, monotone-functions

Prove that$$ \frac {2}{\pi -2}\ \le\ \frac {\sin x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}\ <\ 2$$where $$x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

My Attempt:$$ f'(x)=\frac{ x\sin x(x-\sin x)-(1-\cos x)(\sin x-x\cos x)}{(x-\sin x)^2}=\frac{ x^2\sin x-(1-\cos x)x-\sin x(1-\cos x)}{(x-\sin x)^2}$$

After this not able to get breakthrough.

Comment: No. Both are increasing

Comment: Further $$f'(x)=\frac{\sin x\left(x-\frac{1-\cos x}{2\sin x}(1+\sqrt{5+4\cos x})\right)\left(x-\frac{1-\cos x}{2\sin x}(1-\sqrt{5+4\cos x})\right)}{(x-\sin x)^2}$$ I wonder whether this helps

Comment: I would recommend that you clearly denominators. Can you use the fundamental result that $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x)<g'(x)$ for $0<x<a$ to show that $f(x)<g(x)$ on $[0,a]$?

Comment: One way to do this is to show that $f'$ is negative on the interval, which you can do by using sufficiently high-degree Taylor expansions for sine and cosine, which gives you bounds on the function because they are alternating series.  To see how high of a degree you need, replace the sines and cosines one at a time and compare the graphs of the original function with the approximation using Google's graphing calculator; what you're looking for is an upper bound that is negative on the interval.  You should end up with a polynomial which is much easier to show is negative on the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did by using brute force
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sin x\left(x-\frac{1-\cos x}{2\sin x}(1+\sqrt{5+4\cos x})\right)\left(x-\frac{1-\cos x}{2\sin x}(1-\sqrt{5+4\cos x})\right)}{(x-\sin x)^2}=\frac{\sin x\left(x-\tan \frac{x}{2}(1+\sqrt{5+4\cos x})\right)\left(x-\tan \frac{x}{2}(1-\sqrt{5+4\cos x})\right)}{(x-\sin x)^2}$$

Let $$g(x)=x-\tan \frac{x}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5+4\cos x}\right)$$

$$g'(x)=1-\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5+4\cos x}\right)-\tan \frac{x}{2}.\frac{-4\sin x}{2\sqrt{5+4\cos x}}$$

$$=1-\frac{1+\sqrt{5+4\cos x}}{1+\cos x}+\frac{2(1-\cos x)}{\sqrt{5+4\cos x}}$$

$$=\frac{\cos x\left(\sqrt{5+4\cos x}-4\right)-2\cos^2x-3}{(1+\cos x)\sqrt{5+4\cos x}}<0$$

$g(x)$ is a decreasing function. So,if $x>0$,then $g(x)<g(0)$. *i.e*  $g(x)<0$

Similarly, Let $$h(x)=x-\tan \frac{x}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{5+4\cos x}\right)$$

$$h'(x)=1-\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{5+4\cos x}\right)-\tan \frac{x}{2}.(-1)\frac{-4\sin x}{2\sqrt{5+4\cos x}}$$

$$=1-\frac{1-\sqrt{5+4\cos x}}{1+\cos x}-\frac{2(1-\cos x)}{\sqrt{5+4\cos x}}$$

$$=\frac{\cos x\left(\sqrt{5+4\cos x}+4\right)+2\cos^2x+8}{(1+\cos x)\sqrt{5+4\cos x}}>0$$

$h(x)$ is a increasing function. So,if $x>0$,then $h(x)>h(0)$. *i.e*  $h(x)>0$

Thus it can be concluded that $$f'(x)<0$$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x - x \cos x}{x - \sin x}$$
Now, notice that:

$$f\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\Big) = \frac{2}{2-\pi}$$

And when we try to calculate $f(0)$, we run into trouble (can you see why?)
Let's then evaluate:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x - x \cos x}{x - \sin x}$$
Applying L'Hopital's rule three times gives us:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2\cos x - x \sin x}{\cos x} = 2$$
Hence, we can assume that $f(x)$ "starts" at $2$ and "ends" at $\frac{2}{2-\pi}$. Let's now have a look to $f'(x)$, which you seem to have evaluated correctly:
$$f'(x) = \frac{x^2\sin x−(1−\cos x)x−\sin x(1−\cos x)}{(x−\sin x)^2}$$
Now, given that the equality must hold and that $f(x)$ starts and ends in the given values we previosly determined, it's derivative must be $<0,\forall x$ in the given interval (because $\frac{2}{2-\pi} < 2$) . Since the denominator is always positive, we can look at the sign of the numerator:
$$g(x) = x^2\sin x−(1−\cos x)x−\sin x(1−\cos x)$$
This can be rewritten as:
$$g(x) = x^2 \sin x - (1-\cos x)(x+\sin x)$$
Now, ff $g(x) < 0$ in the interval, we are done: the derivative is always negative, hence the function is strictly decreasing, satisfying then, the equality. The graph of $g(x)$ is shown below:

### [image]

So we can see that it is, in fact, negative. Hence, $f$ is strictly *decrasing* in the interval. It starts at $2$, which the maximum value, and ends up and $\frac{2}{2-\pi}$, which is the minimum, hence the inequeality is satisfied.

**Note:** As alphacapture mentioned now in the comments, you can show that $f'$ is negative in the interval using Taylor series. I personally tought that the graph was quickier and more instructive, however it requires computational tools.

Comment: The reason I mentioned the Taylor series was because just looking at a graph does not provide a proof (at least I don't see any way it does) - how do you know that the derivative isn't positive somewhere, but you're just not zoomed in enough to see?

Comment: I plotted only in the given interval. After that, it can be positive. What matters is only the sign in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: What I'm referring to is the possibility that, say, the function is actually positive at 0.1, but you're just not zoomed in enough to see it.  Or perhaps even that there is a very tall spike at 1 where it is positive, but the spike is so narrow that you can't see it in the graph.

Comment: Sorry, I’ve misunderstood you. One can infer that it will be negative when close to $0$ by a few approximations. But if one wants an exact answer, the analysis you proposed is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

If we can show that $f$ is decreasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, then it is easy to finish by checking the endpoints.

To show that $f$ is decreasing on this interval, it is enough to show that $f'$ is negative on this interval.  You computed
$$f'(x)=\frac{ x^2\sin x-(1-\cos x)x-\sin x(1-\cos x)}{(x-\sin x)^2}$$
which is negative if and only if the numerator is negative.

For convenience, we will rewrite the numerator as
$$x^2\sin x-(1-\cos x)(x+\sin x).$$

We can bound the numerator by using that fact that Taylor series for sine and cosine are alternating series, and therefore truncating it gives us bounds.

For $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, we have
$$x^2\sin x\le x^2(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!})$$
$$(1-\cos x)(x+\sin x)\ge(1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}))(x+(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}))$$
where for the second inequality we use that both factors on the right hand side are positive on this interval.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
&x^2\sin x-(1-\cos x)(x+\sin x)\\
\le &x^2(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}) - (1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}))(x+(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}))\\
=&-\frac{x^7((x^2-30)^2+108)}{725760}
\end{align*}
and we can see that the right hand side is always negative on the interval.

(How did I know how far to expand each Taylor series?  Trial and error.  There might be some way to see how far to expand each using the fact that they Taylor series for the numerator of $f'(x)$ is $O(x^7)$, but I don't see how at the moment.)